# Does a vacuum pump that is part of a larger device need to be ROHS compliant for CE compliance?

Tags: ce, compliance

I am planning to create a product for sale in the European Union. This product will contain a vacuum pump along with associated electronics.

Does the vacuum pump I am including in the unit need to be ROHS compliant as the electronic components will be?

I imagine if the pump is not CE rated individually for interference/radiation/ESD, I can test it as part of the complete equipment.

Comment: "I imagine if the pump is not CE rated individually for interference/radiation/ESD, I can test it as part of the complete equipment."  That's probably true.  Especially since you can add EMI suppression devices or metal enclosures to make it pass those tests.

Comment: Since ROHS is part of the CE compliance ([2011/65/EU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32011L0065)) for electrical and electronic equipment, I would assume the pump would need to be part of the CE compliance for the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be compliant but you can apply for exemptions for the limits. You need the RoHS certificate to all components (also mechanical ones). If you get an exemption or use a component with an exemption for a "substance of concern" you need to report it to SCIP database.

The pump does not have to comply to EMC/ESD-regulations separately if it's only used in a system and the system passes the said regulations.